# unir tres tablas de diferentes hojas en una nueva en excel 2016

Tags: excel

Tengo tres tablas de horarios de tres áreas con los siguientes encabezados de columnas repetidos en la misma ubicación cada uno (único formato):

*área - nombre - turno - fecha - observaciones*

**Nota**: los campos no tienen valores para sumar ni sacar promedio, pues he visto muchos de los videos que hacen ejemplos con estos datos.

La idea es unir las tres tablas en una sola tabla general y cada vez que se actualice las tablas por área se actualice también la tabla general.

He intentado con la herramienta consolidado y no se puede, a su vez intenté con la herramienta relaciones y tampoco pude hacerlo, intenté unir las tres tablas con tablas dinámicas con la opción "más tablas" pero los encabezados u otro campos no me sales al mismo nivel sino escalonado por ser de diferentes tablas.

Hago hincapié que es con excel 2016 y no tiene la función `apilarv` ni la funcion `stack` ni la función `unir` ni `consolidar`. Tampoco puedo usar la herramienta usar datos externos ya que no la cuenta y tampoco tengo power query ni vba.

Agradezco el tiempo que se puedan dar para apoyarme quizá con fórmula matricial u otra pues con macro se me hace más confuso

Comment: Por favor, lee [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y no olvides leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Visita también el  [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). as preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores.

Comment: Primero, no son tablas, son hojas de calculo.. que se vean como tablas, no las hace tablas, pues si fueran tablas esto seria trivial. Segundo, vas a tener que programar una macro que las pegue una abajo de otra.. no es tan complejo...